# A Rectangle Divided into Different Shapes with Equal Areas

Tags: geometry, contest-math

I am trying to solve this problem:

[image]

but really am not sure as to how to start with the solution.  Would really appreciate any help.  Thank you

Comment: Hint: The area of the $c+d$ rectangle is twice the area of the $b$ rectangle, but they have the same width. So ...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply and for the hint.  I seem to have gotten stuck on the thought that the length/height of the b rectangle is one-half of the length/height of the c+d rectangle.  Not sure how to proceed from there, sorry.  Thanks again for your help

Comment: If the height of the $b$ rectangle is half the height of the $c+d$ rectangle, then how does it compare to the height of the $a$ rectangle?

Comment: Thanks for all the tips I was finally able to reach the answer, that is the length of b is 4.5 times longer that its width :)

Comment: Glad to help. You should post your solution as an answer, to prevent the Math.SE system from periodically bumping this question to the top of the Unanswered Questions queue.